Cannot input floating point values in TextField Material UI
Many suggestions online said to use inputProps with the step attribute but the problem is that it will be deprecated.
I have tried using the step attribute outside of inputProps but it does not work at all.
If I input 1.2, it will say to enter 1 or 2 instead.
<TextField
  fullWidth
  required
  id="amount-field"
  margin="dense"
  label="Amount ($)"
  type="number"
  step={0.01} // step="any" doesn't work as well
/>

I am expecting to be able to input floating point values like 1.2 or 2.50 with no issues but it's not working.

Material UI recommends against using type='number' (you can see their reasons why here). There is also a github issue in the MUI repo about adding a number input to MUI that has been going on since Jan 9, 2020 (4+ years seems like a long time to add a number input ). I would suggest using a library like react-number-format, which allows you to pass a custom input (they even use MUI's TextField in their example).
Here's an example on how you could create a reusable number input combining react-number-format and MUI's <TextField />:
import { NumericFormat, NumericFormatProps } from 'react-number-format';
import { TextField, TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material';

export type NumberInputProps = NumericFormatProps<TextFieldProps>;

export default function NumberInput(props: NumberInputProps) {
  return <NumericFormat customInput={TextField} {...props} />;
}

Then you could use it like so:
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(12345);

  return (
    <NumberInput
      // NumericFormat props
      value={value}
      onValueChange={({ floatValue }) => floatValue && setValue(floatValue)}
      // TextField props
      fullWidth
      required
      id="amount-field"
      margin="dense"
      label="Amount ($)"
    />
  );
}

Here is a working example.
